# Why is perspective not applied to the children of the container?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm making a 3D floorplan with 4 floors and want to apply the same perspective to all floors. That turns out to be a problem.

For unrelated reasons, I have to put wrappers around the divs that will contain the actual floor plan images. The structure looks like this:

```html
<div class="map"> <!-- Has perspective applied -->
  <div class="floor"> <!-- Wrapper that will not be transformed (to catch mouse events. Is repeated 4 times in the example on codepen -->
    <div class="plan"> <!-- contains a floorplan and gets a 3D transformation. It should get the same perspective as div.map. -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The difference between getting perspective from a parent and from an individual's own stacking context is demonstrated on this codepen: https://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/JImvb

It seems that the wrappers (div.floor) in my example introduce new stacking contexts, creating perspective for each floor individually. This makes the .plan div inside each .floor div to get perspective with its own set of perspective lines. I need all .plan divs to get the same perspective and not just inherit the property from .map.

Here's the code with the issue: https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/OzMQjO

The relevant SCSS lines are (I think):

```
.map{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  perspective: 90px;
}

.floor{
  position: relative;
  transition: padding ease-in 300ms;

  &.active{

    .plan{
      transform: translateX(120px) translateY(-100px) rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(20deg);      
    }  
  }
  }    
  .plan{
    transform: perspective(900px) translateX(120px) translateY(-100px) translateZ(0px) rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(60deg);
    transition: all ease-in 300ms;
  }
}

.floor:nth-child(1) .plan{
    z-index: 40;
}
.floor:nth-child(2) .plan{
    z-index: 30;
}
.floor:nth-child(3) .plan{
    z-index: 10;
}
.floor:nth-child(4) .plan{
    z-index: 0;
}
```

As you can see, .floor has position: relative, but no own z-index. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) that should not create a new stacking context.

Comment: I don't udnerstand well what you have in mind, but if you want some CSS to be applied on an element, and her "sons", you can put it like this: .map, .map>*{ property: value; }
I don't even know if i explained it well. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Joël, thanks for the hint, but as you can see, the perspective property is inherited by the children. Because of the stacking context introduced by the wrappers, this looks off nonetheless. I edited my question, I hope now it is clearer.

Comment: can you, please, detail in your post which element must take which property and does not? It could simplify me the inspecting a lot of much as i can reach a reason for your behaviour regarding css + js workflow. Thx

Comment: .plan should get the same visual perspective as .map. The issue is not that the property is not inherited, because it is. The problem seems to be in getting a new stacking context. The JS should be irrelevant.

Comment: Figured it out now! Thanks for asking questions to get to the core of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrapper divs (.floor) need:

```css
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style